# Getting a file descriptor from a filename in a POSIX system - or how to close a file having only the filename

Tags: file, posix

Could you please help me with an opposite issue? I need to close a file, but I am only given a filename (I presume I need to convert it to a file descriptor). Is it possible at all, and if so - in which way? Thanks.

Comment: What if the file is open by more than one process/handle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using POSIX standard APIs? No.

On some linux systems, you might be able to figure it out via /proc/PID/fd.

Comment: Unfortunately I've wanted to do so via POSIX API. Thus, the solution was to hold a local mapping from the file name to its sytem number...

Answer (score 0):

You can't close a file for another process. If it's in your process, you should keep either a filehandle or a file descriptor around; or you might use `/proc/self/fd` as bmargulies suggested.